# How to dynamically translate qt applications?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, translation

I have a program in two languages english and arabic, in files called app_en and app_ar. I am able to translate the program at the start in main using installTranslator in QApplication. My question is how can I change the language of the program with a push of a QAction?

Here is my attempt:

I have My language QAction connected to a slot which gets user's language of choose then saves it and goes to another function to install the translation. This all happens outside the QMainWindow.

```
void MainCore::GetAndSaveLanguage(bool){
    //Getting the language the users wants.
    bool OKPressed;
    QString Language = QInputDialog::getItem(NULL, InputDialogString, InputDialogString + ":", Languages, 0, false, &OKPressed)
                        .remove(QRegExp("*(", Qt::CaseSensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard)).remove(')');

    //Checking if ok button was pressed.
    if(OKPressed){
        //Saving the languages.
        Settings->beginGroup("Settings");
        Settings->setValue("Language", Language);
        Settings->endGroup();

        //Update language.
        UpdateTranslations(Language);
     }
}

void MainCore::UpdateTranslations(QString Language){
    //Setting the translation for the qt widgets.
    QTranslator QtTranslator;
    QtTranslator.load("qt_" + Language, QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
    QApplication::instance()->installTranslator(&QtTranslator);

    //Setting the translation for the program.
    QTranslator AppTranslator;
    AppTranslator.load("app_" + Language, ":/translations");
    QApplication::instance()->installTranslator(&AppTranslator);
}
```

I also have on the QMainWindow a function which sets all the text of the screen like this:

```
void Window::SetText(){
     Menu->setTitle(tr("File"));
     ...
}
```

This is called when the windows is constructed and in the changeEvent function:

```
void Window::changeEvent(QEvent *event){
    if(event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange){
        SetText();
    }else{
        QWidget::changeEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you allocate your QtTranslator (Same for AppTranslator) in the stack, and it goes out of scope in the end of UpdateTranslations

```
void MainCore::UpdateTranslations(QString Language)
{
  //Setting the translation for the qt widgets.
  QTranslator QtTranslator;
  QtTranslator.load("qt_" + Language,QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
  QApplication::instance()->installTranslator(&QtTranslator); // this is a bad reference

  ...
} // QtTranslator will go out of scope
```

you need QtTranslator to live as long as your app is running. So one option is to allocate it in the heap

```
QTranslator * QtTranslator = new QTranslator;
```

and you need to keep a reference to QtTranslator to be able to delete it later...

Comment: Since QTranslator is a QObject, probably the best way to control the lifetime would be to make it a child of the QApplication instance.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion! I could fix it during several hours